# Question lists build on favourite tag list

Tags: feature-request, tagging, user-interface, bookmarks

What I would like is to have lists of questions that only lists the questions that have one or more of my favourite tags attached, so that I can have a quick view of newest or featured questions in any of my favourite fields.

Answer (score 4):

Copy/paste/edited from Jeff Atwood's answer over on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101575/148069):

> There is a default tag filter on http://stackexchange.com/ but you
>   must be logged in:
>
> 1. Click on "Filtered Questions"
> 2. Click on "Favourite Tags" filter.
>
> [image]

Comment: Can robjohn's bookmarklet be used to render math on that page? I never tried because I actually prefer non-rendered previews, but someone may be interested.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it is a bit complicated, can it not be in some way be integrated in the mathematics site? also you cannot select the featured questions this way (but that is minor), btw i don;t want the filter to be active all the time just when i start up.

Answer (score 2):

You can create and bookmark a URL of the form

```
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag1+or+tag2+or+tag3+or+tag4
```

For example, 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability+or+linear-algebra+or+measure-theory+or+statistics

You can use the *featured* and other sub-tabs to customize the view further.

If you have only a few favorite tags, the above is equivalent to searching for

```
[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3] or [tag4]
```

If you have many favorite tags, they may not fit into the search box (which takes only 240 characters), but you can use a text editor to create the URL as above.